# Is every even regular and even order of a graph, class 1?

Tags: graph-theory

I researched about graphs and I found that every even regular graphs with odd number of vertices is class 2. I don't find any even regular graph with even order such that is class 2. So I guess every even regular graph with even order is class 1. Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true. Here are two counterexamples, one of them connected, taken from Arrigo Bonisoli & David Cariolario, [*Excessive Factorizations of Regular Graphs*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.102.17&rep=rep1&type=pdf) [PDF].

[image: Class 2 graphs of even order.]

Each is regular of degree $4$, and both are class $2$. This is quite easy to verify by brute force in the case of the top graph; the bottom one takes a bit more work.